# Trying to set code::blocks dark theme. Error-Unable to initialize gtk, is DISPLAY set properly?

Tags: codeblocks

I'am trying to install dark theme for `code::blocks` for `ubuntu` from [here](https://medium.com/@yzhong.cs/change-editor-theme-for-code-blocks-windows-linux-mac-92e9c15cbca4). But when I execute the command `sudo cb_share_config` in the `terminal` , I got the `Error` : `Unable to initialize gtk, is DISPLAY set properly?`. I'am very much obessed by white theme and desperately needs dark theme. Can somebody please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you would want to enable X-access from the terminal by executing `sudo xhost +`. Then run the command `sudo cb_share_config` and you get the desired result. Hope this helps :)